# python access CONSTANT from another class

Tags: python

I want to pass on CONSTANT from another class as a dynamic variable.

```
class A:
    MATCH_ALL = 0
    MATCH_ANY = 1
    MATCH_NON = 3

    def setMatchType(matchType):
        assert(type in [MATCH_ALL, MATCH_ANY, MATCH_NON])
        print type
```

In another file

```
import A
class B:
    def makeAchoice():
         instanceA = A()
         instanceA.setMatchType(instanceA.MATCH_ANY)
```

However, I want add a variable on makeAchoice, so setMatchType value could be dynamic.

```
import A
class B:
    def makeAchoice(matchType=MATCH_ANY):
         instanceA = A()
         instanceA.setMatchType(?)
```

How do I pass on constant as Variable in ? above?

I try with
getattr(instanceA, matchType)
so I could access the constant first, but it seems not working.

Comment: if you're using a constant on several classes and you don't want to keep them under a namespace, why not just declare them directly or import them from a common place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just access it with `A.CONSTANT_NAME`:

```
import A
class B:
    def makeAchoice(matchType=A.MATCH_ANY):
         instanceA = A()
         instanceA.setMatchType(A.MATCH_ANY)
```

Comment: but when I use makeAchoice somehwhere else, do I need to specify the class name of A, like makeAchoice(A.MATCH_ANY)?

Comment: yes, you'll always need to do `A.MATCH_NON`, etc., wherever you access those constants. If you don't want to do that, then you should define them in `A.py`, but outside of `class A:`.

Comment: I was thinking I could access the constant from one of the instance of A. But I just realized instance just for running the method and I have import A already, thanks!

Comment: Hi Jakob, I just try that, and if I want to use Class B in another class, for example Class C, it seems I have to import A, so A.MATCH_ANY could be access. is there anywhere I only pass on MATCH_ANY when I use the method of makeAchoice in C? I know there is work around of from A import *, but I am trying to avoid of using import *

Comment: you could do `import A` instead of `from A import *` (since you refer to the constant with `A.`), or you could put the constants in `B`, since it seems to be using them more.